# Get all exchange server contacts in SQL database which is installed on different computers

Tags: sql, exchange-server, contacts

I am getting problem in fetching contacts information from exchange server or AD to SQL server database.

Basically O want to synchronize between Active Directory users with my database. AD, Exchange, SQL is installed on different computer but all are on same domain.

I tried different methods but didn't get any success.
Please tell me if any one tried it before.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
GO
reconfigure with override
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
GO
reconfigure with override
GO

SELECT Name, displayName,givenname,distinguishedName, 
      SAMAccountName
FROM 
OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject','adsdatasource' ,
'SELECT  Name, displayName,givenname,distinguishedName, 
      SAMAccountName
    FROM ''LDAP://doaminname.domainname.tld/ou=Groupname,
      dc=Computername,dc=domain name,dc=NET'' 
    WHERE Name = ''username''')
GO
```

This code giving the error:

> Error Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   An error occurred while preparing the query

```
"SELECT  Name, displayName, givenname, distinguishedName, 
  SAMAccountName   From  FROM ''LDAP://doaminname.domainname.tld/ou=Groupname,
  dc=Computername,dc=domain name,dc=NET'' 
WHERE Name = ''username''') for execution against OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "(null)".
```

Comment: So provide us your trys would be a nice beginning ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Your Support I got Answer for this Question.

All my code is working fine but problem is in AD Security config. 
after fixing that and replacing Ldap string my code work fine ..

Check if Security is not issue from your side please check LDAP string Once again. 
If you are using Ad-Hoc then try give IP address  "LDAP://192.168.*.*" of your AD Server.

Thanks for you support.